# How can two elements of group $S_4$ generate the whole group $S_4$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I struggle to prove that two elements of non-cyclic group $S_4$ can generate the whole group.
The task is to find at least two such couples too.

I suppose that this is somehow connected with the order of the permutation. I know that the highest order of permutation (I take a permutation as an element of group $S_4$) is $4$. But how can be this applied when I want to work with $2$ elements? 
I know that another approach could be to take any two elements and try to generate the group..
Thank you very much.

Comment: $(1234) \in S_4$ has order $4$.

Comment: The probability that two random non-identity elements of $S_4$ that do not both lie in $A_4$ generate $S_4$ is $6/11$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since any permutation can be written as a product of cycles, and any cycle can be written as a product of transpositions by using the rule

$$(c_1c_2....c_k) = (c_1c_k)(c_1c_{k-1}) \cdots (c_1c_2)$$

We can immediately conclude that $S_n$ is generated by all of the transpositions. Our next step is to

show that we can actually restrict our generating set to the transpositions of

the form $(i \ \ i+1$). These are sometimes called simple transpositions. That is,

$\\$

$$S_n=\big<(12)(23)(34)\cdots (n-1,n) \big> \\ $$

Since any permutation can be written as a product of cycles, and we've already shown that any cycle

can be written as a product of 2-cycles, all we need to show is that any 2-cyle can be written as a

product of the simple cycles $(e.g. \ (23),(56),etc.)$. For example,

.

$$ \\ (14) = (12)(23)(34)(23)(12) \\ $$ The proof is as follows:

**Lemma**: Any transposition $(ab)$ can be written as a product of simple transpositions.

$ \\ $

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$:

We induct on $k = b-a$. $($ for instance the $k=3$ cycles would be $(14),(25),(36)$ etc.

Basis step: For $k = 1$,  $ \quad b-a = 1 \implies (a\ b) = (a \ a+1) $ which is already in the correct form.

$ \\ $

Induction step: Suppose that any transposition of the form $(ab)$ where $b-a = k$
can be written as

a product of simple cycles and let $(ab)$ be a transposition with $b-a = k+1$.

Note that $$(a \ b) = (a \ a+1) (a+1 \ b) (a \ a+1)$$.

Since  $b-(a+1) = b-a-1 = k$ the induction hypothesis tells us that $(a+1 \ \ b)$ is a product of

simple transpositions and hence so is $(ab)$. This is easiest to see with an example.

Lets use  $(14)$ again. We write $(14) = (12)(24)(12)$.

Now we apply the same trick to $(24)$ and write $(24) = (23)(34)(23)$.

Substituting this in we have $$(14) = (12)(24)(12)=(12)(23)(34)(23)(12)$$

$ \\ $

So now we have succeeded in showing that $S_n$ is generated by the simple transpositions. Hence to

show that $S_n = \big<(12)(12 \dots n)\big>$, we now only need to show that each of the simple transpositions

can be obtained from $(12) \text{ and } (12\cdots n)$. Clearly the $(12)$ case is already taken care of.

$ \\ $

Let $\sigma = (12\cdots n)$. Note that $\sigma (12) \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(1),\sigma(2)) = (23)$ Reasoning inductively, we see that

$ \\ $

$$\sigma^k (12) \sigma^{-k} = (k+1 \ k+2) $$

and in this way we obtain all of the simple transpositions and therefore all of $S_n$

$ \\ $
Note: This result can actually be strengthened to $S_n = \big<(ab)(12\cdots n)\big>$ whenever

$gcd(b-a,n) = 1$. Furthermore, ANY transposition and ANY p-cycle will generate $S_p$ if p is prime.

EDIT:

Here I'm letting $\sigma = (12 \cdots n)$. Its a general theorem that for any permutation, call it $\tau$ to avoid confusion, that $\tau (c_1c_2\cdots c_k)\tau^{-1} = (\tau(c_1) \tau(c_2) \cdots \tau(c_k))$. If you haven't learned this you can just visually inspect it one at a time. For instance $(1234)(12)(4321) = (23)$., then $(1234)(23)(4321) = (34)$. So now we have shown that its possible to get $(12),(23),(34)$, from $(12),(1234)$, that its then possible to get any 2-cycle from $(12),(23),(34)$,that is possible to get any cycle from all the 2-cycles, and that its then possible to get any permutation from all the cycles.

Comment: this is a bit complicated to me.Firstly,  I do not understand the inductionstep, why do we want this $(a b)=(a a+1)(a+1 b)(a a+1)$ ?

Comment: Sry was super rushed when i typed that up. You want to show that every permutation can be written as a product of transpositions of the form $(k \ k+1)$ (e.g. $(12) ,(23), (34),$ etc. By the induction step $(a+1,b)$ can  be written in that form and therefore so can (ab).By first writing $(a+1,b)$ in that form and then putting $(a,a+1)$ on both sides of it. If that's still unclear let me know and i'll clean it up and make it clearer. I wasn't sure where you were in algebra

Comment: (ok) so in the induction step we assume that $(a+1,b)$ can be obtained from $(ab)$ ? but why did we add $(a,a+1)$ on both sides ? is that still equivalent then ?

Comment: I put an example of how the induction works in there now. The induction step should hopefully be way clearer.

Comment: yea, it is, thank you very much :) and could you please explain a bit more that part with $σ$ too? I do not understand, what that symbol means hear, and why should the equation $σ(12)σ−1=(σ(1),σ(2))=(23)$ be true.

Comment: Sure see the last paragraph I added.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give another way to think about it.  Using a transposition and an n-cycle, you can generate all the transpositions.  You finish by applying the bubble sort algorithm to generate all the possible permutations of $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $S_3 = \langle (12), (123) \rangle$. Can you generalize this to $S_4$? Can you generalize this to $S_n$?

Comment: So for S4 i have to take [(123),(1234)] and for Sn [(1,2,3...n-1),(1,2, ... n)] ? But how to prove , that it is possible in general ?

Comment: Your guess is a reasonable generalization, but I think the generalization @lhf is trying to get you to go for is $S_n = \langle (12),(12\ldots n) \rangle$.

Comment: There isn't really any way for you to guess this but I think the generalization @lhf is suggesting is $S_n = \langle (12), (12 \ldots n) \rangle$.

Comment: @martina: Your elements of order 3 and 4 generate a subgroup of $S_4$ of order a multiple of 12, as the orders of elements have to divide the order of the group containing them. If you happen to know that $A_4$ is the only subgroup of $S_4$ of order 12, then you are done, as it does not contain an element of order 4.